# How to repeat last magit search and modify an option?

Tags: magit

Searching through the git log with magit is a breeze. When I do a complex search, I may pass five arguments. If I then realize I want to search again with one option changed, how can I get all search options back? I think a long time ago, this was the default behavior of magit, but these days every search starts with the default arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Ah the manual is better than I thought. I'm not sure if I can get back options of the last search but inside the log buffer, pressing `l` again shows the buffer-local search options. And `L` provides options to save current options as defaults for the future. See https://magit.vc/manual/magit/Refreshing-Logs.html#Refreshing-Logs